# How to disable Bootstrap form validation (without jQuery)?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an AngularJS application that uses Bootstrap (v3) for styling. I want to disable the Bootstrap form validation in one of my forms, which automatically gives my input field a green or red glow when a user types in content or leaves the input field empty, respectively.

Is there a way to do this using an HTML/CSS/JavaScript override? I do not want to edit the original Bootstrap files, nor do I want to use jQuery.

Note: I read that you can achieve this using jQuery with `$(#form).data('bootstrapValidator').enableFieldValidators('input', false)`, but as I mentioned: I do not want to use jQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might be confused.  Bootstrap Validator is a separate jQuery plugin.  It is not part of the Bootstrap framework.  Bootstrap itself does not provide any kind validation.  There are some styles that you can apply to uniformly style forms when you perform validation through some other means.  If you're using AngularJS, I'd look and see if there is an ng-class combined with the ngModelController using $error and $valid that is perhaps applying the Bootstrap has-error or has-success classes.  If you post your code, it would be easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own CSS file that defines the same styles as Bootstrap, like `.has-error`. As long as your CSS file is parsed later, you will override their implementation. Alternatively you can add `!important` and then you dont need to worry about order.

Note though that this could have unintended consequences, as you are fully overriding Bootstrap in this case.